# Holt-Winters parameters in R

Tags: r, time-series, parameterization, exponential-smoothing

I'm trying to replicate some values from a holt winters calculation made in excel by someone else. I have the time series time_x, and I'm using the forecast package.

The problem is when I run the command hw using the same parameters this error occur:

`>hw(y = time_x,h = 24,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.6, gamma = 0.05)`

`[1] "Model: ETS(A,A,A)" Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
Parameters out of range`

Aren't all parameters between 0 and 1?

Comment: It could mean that the ets function tries to optimize the phi parameter and fails to get it within the bounds 0.8 and 1. You could try to specify this parameter in the hw() or change the bounds in ets()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the conditions you need to follow (or use bounds="admissible" in the function call):

in your case you have $\beta>\alpha$, which triggers the check.param function to return 0

```
check.param <- function(alpha,beta,gamma,phi,lower,upper,bounds,m)
{
  if(bounds != "admissible")
  {
    if(!is.null(alpha))
    {
      if(alpha < lower[1] | alpha > upper[1])
        return(0)
    }
    if(!is.null(beta))
    {
      if(beta < lower[2] | beta > alpha | beta > upper[2])
        return(0)
    }
    if(!is.null(phi))
    {
      if(phi < lower[4] | phi > upper[4])
        return(0)
    }
    if(!is.null(gamma))
    {
      if(gamma < lower[3] | gamma > 1-alpha | gamma > upper[3])
        return(0)
    }
  }
  if(bounds != "usual")
  {
    if(!admissible(alpha,beta,gamma,phi,m))
      return(0)
  }
  return(1)
}
```

from the source code
https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/ets.R